# Ошибка при удалении, а потом создании заново li элементов

Tags: javascript

Есть массив:

```
let S_NAMES = [{
        aboutFull: 'Full about',
        site: 'https://google.com',
        telegram: 'https://t.me/telegram',
        func: ['Li #1', 'Li #2']
    },
    {
        aboutFull: 'Full about',
        site: 'https://google.com',
        telegram: 'https://t.me/telegram',
        func: ['Li #3', 'Li #4']
    }];
let arrServices = S_NAMES;
```

При нажатии на кнопку всплывает окно, в котором в списке `ul` с `ID` `list` создаётся свой `li` и  заполняется из массива вся информация.

```
  const list = document.getElementById('list');
  for(i = 0; i < S_NAMES[index].func.length; i++){

    let liItem = document.createElement('li')
    liItem.innerText = S_NAMES[index].func[i]
    liItem.className = 'services__func-item';

    list.append(liItem)
  }
```

Вроде как всё работает, только когда это всплывающее окно закрывается с информацией, я удаляю эти li, чтобы при следующем запуске он не дублировал их и создавал заново `li`

```
btnClose.addEventListener('click', function () {
        $(".services__func-item").remove();
    });
```

Вроде и удаляет, но при следующем запуске ошибка:
[image: Вроде и удаляет, но при следующем запуске ошибка:]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Плохо задан вопрос. Код кодом не тот, что на картинке. Где он вызывается - неизвестно. Что такое `index` - непонятно.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4m156Lk8/

Comment: Меня только ошибка тревожит, почему так происходит?

Comment: В фидле ошибки нет.

Comment: Может я неправильным путем пошел заполнения li элементов...

Answer (score 0):

```
const list = document.getElementById('list');
  for(let i = 0; i < S_NAMES[index].func.length; i++){

    let liItem = document.createElement('li')
    liItem.innerText = S_NAMES[index].func[i]
    liItem.className = 'services__func-item';

    list.append(liItem)
  }
```

Ошибка была в том, что я не объявил переменную i. Было просто `for(i = 0...);`

Всё заработало как надо.